# how to remove auto_bcc in Postfix (Zimbra)

Tags: postfix, zimbra

Hi I added a auto_bcc in my postfix config, and now I don't know how to remove it.

This is what I did:

Per user bcc for Zimbra

in `/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf`, create a file called `sender_bcc` and added the user you wanted to copy/send to:

```
employee@domain.com boss@domain.com
```

in `/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/main.conf`, add:

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/sender_bcc
```

then run as zimbra user

```
postmap /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/sender_bcc
```

And restart all the stuff:

```
postfix reload
postfix stop
postfix start
```

How do I remove that? it seems like it created a database entry or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to disable the functionality, remove or comment out the line you added to main.cf.

The postmap command you ran generated a .db file, which lets Postfix do more efficient lookups than if it were to parse the text file every time.  Both the sender_bcc and sender_bcc.db files are safe to remove after you remove the sender_bcc_maps line from main.cf and reload or restart Postfix.